# Dr. Racket: Removing elements from a list using abstract list functions

Tags: list, scheme, racket

So when given two lists, how do I remove elements in one list from another using only map, filter or foldr? I can't use explicit recursion or lambda either.

The lists consist of only numbers that are sorted in ascending order.

For example, if given (list 1 2 3) and (list 1 3 5), I want to remove all of the second list's elements from the first list. The output I want is (list 2).
If given (list 4 5 6) and (list  2 3 5), I would get (list 4 6).

I'm guessing the final code would be something like:

```
(define (fn-name list-one list-two)
    (filter ... list-one))
```

Thanks!

Comment: Odd requirements. Is it an exercise? If so can you show where it is from (that makes it easier to understand the context).

Comment: There's also function for that in srfi/1 called  lset-difference,  for those who don't want to write this function.

Answer (score 1):

Given that you're using Racket, we can write a simple solution in terms of some of the built-in abstract list functions and without using explicit `lambda`s, we only need a little help from [`SRFI-26`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/srfi/srfi-std/srfi-26.html). Try this:

```
(require srfi/26)

(define (difference lst1 lst2)
  (filter-not (cut member <> lst2) lst1))
```

It works as expected:

```
(difference (list 1 2 3) (list 1 3 5))
=> '(2)

(difference (list 4 5 6) (list 2 3 5))
=> '(4 6)
```

Answer (score 0):

You use filter, but you have to curry and invert `member` so you cannot do it without `lambda`.

```scheme
(define (remove-elements needles haystack)
  (filter (lambda (x) (not (member ...))) 
          haystack))


(define (remove-elements needles haystack)
  (define (not-in-needles x)
    (not (member ...)))

  (filter not-in-needles haystack))
```

Both of these use `lambda` twice! Once for the `define` of `remove-elements` and once explicit / in `not-in-needles`. In your own example you use `lambda` once too since `(define (name . args) . body)` is the same as `(define name (lambda args . body))`